# SMS syncing in Outlook

Tags: email, sync, privacy, forwarding, sms

I have recently left a company and have picked up that they have not disabled my mail account and that all mails have been forwarded via a rule to alternative people in the company.  The company automatically set up our emails and sms's to sync with our phones.  Does this mean that the people that my mail has been forwarded to has automatically been receiving copies of my sms' as well?

Comment: Mostly likely.  Did you have your personal phone synced up with your job's Outlook client?

Comment: Oh and What device do you use?

Comment: Yip, the company requested that we use our personal phones for work mail access.  Samsung Galaxy II.  I have since deleted the mail box off my phone and other personal devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
1) Open the e-mail client program on the Samsung

2) Go to "menu | account settings"

3) Disable SMS-sync
```

Hope this does it for you, from this point forward.  And if you have done it already, from what I have read, that should have take care of SMS syncing.

Comment: Cool thanks!  I can kick myself - I left the company end of last week already and forgot about the whole sms syncing story.  I think I am going to be okay for everything before now because the forwarding rule was very specific in that the mail had to be addressed to my work email specifically in order to be forwarded.  I am thinking that because this does not apply to the sms's they might not have been forwarded automatically.  Wishfull thinking or no?

Comment: @CAT It might be.  I would disable it ASAP, since I am not the one who set that up on your phone, I wouldn't know if it's wishful thinking or not, but I would take all needed step to make sure no personal SMS would get forwarded by mistake, especially if it wasn't a voluntary termination of employment.  Situation like yours is exactly why I do not use my private and personal phone in business setting, they can afford to provide needed employees with a mobile phone, no reason to piggy bank off of personal phone.  Good luck!